# getting all corresponding max values in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (pandas version 0.13.1)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> DF = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['G1','G1','G2','G2'],'Start':['10','10','12','13'],'End':['13','13','14','15'],'Sample':['S1','S2','S3','S3'],'Status':['yes','yes','no','yes'],'pValue':[0.13,0.12,0.96,0.76],'pValueString':['13/100','12/100','96/100','76/100'],'desc':['aaaaaa','bbbbbb','aaaaaa','cccccc']})
>>> DF
  End Group Sample Start Status  pValue pValueString desc
0  13    G1     S1    10    yes    0.13       13/100 aaaaaa   
1  13    G1     S2    10     no    0.12       12/100 bbbbbb
2  14    G2     S3    12     no    0.96       96/100 aaaaaa
3  15    G2     S3    13    yes    0.76       76/100 cccccc
```

[4 rows x 8 columns]

To the dataframe above

1. I would like to groupby 'Group'.
2. Then groupby a Start-End couplet.
3. Pivot the sample values for each group. aggregate by max(pValue)
4. Get the corresponding Status, desc corresponding to the sample with the higher pvalue and replace its value with a pValueString.

I need to ultimately get this to the following format

```
Group Start End Sample           Status  desc
                    S1   S2
G1    10    13    13/100 12/100  yes     aaaaaa
                    S3
G2    12    14    96/100         no      aaaaaa
      13    15    76/100         yes     cccccc
```

I have tried to use pivot_table and groupby but to no avail.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I have

```
grouped=DF.groupby('Group')
for g,v in grouped:
    pandas.pivot_table(data=v,values=['pValue','pValueString']),rows= ['Group','Start','End'],cols=['Sample'])['pValueString']
```

How do I get the corresponding desc and Status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find your values for desc and Status:

```
groups = DF.groupby(['Group','Start','End'])
maxvals = groups.apply(lambda x: x.sort('pValue', ascending = False).head(1))
maxvals = maxvals[['Status','desc']].reset_index()    
maxvals
Out[69]: 
  Group Start End  level_3 Status    desc
0    G1    10  13        0    yes  aaaaaa
1    G2    12  14        2     no  aaaaaa
2    G2    13  15        3    yes  cccccc
```

Create your pivot table separately:

```
pvt = DF.pivot_table(index =['Group','Start','End'], 
                     columns = 'Sample', 
                     values = 'pValueString', 
                     aggfunc = max).reset_index()
pvt

Out[70]: 
Sample               S1      S2      S3
Group Start End                        
G1    10    13   13/100  12/100     NaN
G2    12    14      NaN     NaN  96/100
      13    15      NaN     NaN  76/100
```

Finally merge the two together

```
pd.merge(pvt, maxvals)
Out[73]: 
Sample Group Start End      S1      S2      S3  level_3 Status    desc
0         G1    10  13  13/100  12/100     NaN        0    yes  aaaaaa
1         G2    12  14     NaN     NaN  96/100        2     no  aaaaaa
2         G2    13  15     NaN     NaN  76/100        3    yes  cccccc
```

Comment: Just wondering if it would be possible to not print the 'level' column.
Also would it be possible to sort each Group value by the corresponding Sample values?

Answer (score 1):

Create an index of Groups with the highest pValues (per Sample for a given Start and End within the group):

```
idx = DF.groupby(['Group', 'Start', 'End']).pValue.agg(lambda x: x.idxmax())
```

Use this index to get the status and desc:

```
a = DF.ix[idx][['Status', 'desc']]
>>> a
  Status    desc
0    yes  aaaaaa
2     no  aaaaaa
3    yes  cccccc
```

Then get the max pValue per Group/Sample (in pivot table form).

```
b = DF.groupby(['Group', 'Start', 'End', 'Sample']).pValue.max().unstack()
>>> b
Sample             S1    S2    S3
Group Start End                  
G1    10    13   0.13  0.12   NaN
G2    12    14    NaN   NaN  0.96
      13    15    NaN   NaN  0.76
```

Finally, set the index of the previous DataFrame to the index of the new one and join.

```
a.index = b.index
df_new = b.join(a)
>>> df_new
                   S1    S2    S3 Status    desc
Group Start End                                 
G1    10    13   0.13  0.12   NaN    yes  aaaaaa
G2    12    14    NaN   NaN  0.96     no  aaaaaa
      13    15    NaN   NaN  0.76    yes  cccccc
```